# How do I expand the Twitter sidebar?

Tags: twitter

The Twitter sidebar has [collapsed](https://l447bq.by.files.1drv.com/y4p0w1iFzk7oE4zYxjQy2HiY3lL08orF0AIDJbuXMF3GiqFYarEDR7D7xXtSJYSGA0B5Wfos5NHZiQf8lrsxsP3QNCu86P7WZ-VG9da3D_hNYMgWYfz_MNYkI25YVC2BUiagKQxxVMyUOptBcZ6rWO2Q1Lpr2YuBZ_tfkQC_Y5tBBJCmoviueer8dSdqdVbi8e1yyjsBaDKukSzxCb706hWRR-J3IxhUZ-Q9AcDlIwH-eA/collapse.png?psid=1). How do I [expand](https://gafu7a.by.files.1drv.com/y4pUx07sYNxzaDznhbZXdGX0RFb52v5y1H3U9aihkg9WgfSjhm923g-OhlJiLBh75Gw76oQThCm9K6vuF-jyBeeew-lJA6v4SnlcUwHURxoRF0ykw_30nFqM9J2MWQNjZ0ccABBV2JmZu2r_wgzoJh1fA6DPU48_-S_sKQm1imu1S_Au3xpgtJUYCUxQvqg6rdFtKjzHIY_bFhdjdGcazoCVskBe_Agv7WVYDLSgishTzg/expand.png?psid=1) it?

I can't find an official Twitter forum. Someone has [asked](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/h915ps/i_accidentally_shrunk_the_twitter_sidebar_somehow/) this question in Reddit. I tried posting my own question but it was removed without explanatian.

Comment: Both the links collapsed and expand is not working. Better to add screenshot to make clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expanded and collapsed sidebar is displayed based on the screen size. If the available width is **> 1280px**, it shows the sidebar with icons and names. On smaller screens, it just shows the icons. You can test it by opening twitter on desktop and slowly minimizing the window.

Here's screenshots of custom device width in developer tools

1280px:

[image]

1281px:

[image]